# How to you activate drag and order mode immediately after you tap on a button

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Based on https://github.com/pgpt10/DragAndDrop-CollectionView

By using

```
self.collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
self.collectionView.dragDelegate = self
self.collectionView.dropDelegate = self
```

Once you **long press** anywhere within a collection view cell, the following function will be triggered

```
extension DragDropViewController : UICollectionViewDragDelegate
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem]
    {
        let item = collectionView == collectionView1 ? self.items1[indexPath.row] : self.items2[indexPath.row]
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: item as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        return [dragItem]
    }
```

---

However, I have a different requirement.

I have a collection which looks as the following

[image]

I wish when user tap (not long press) on the right 3 horizontal lines icon, he can immediately perform drag and reorder. Tapping other region, or long press on the cell, will not have drag and reorder effect.

May I know how can I achieve so?

---

**Some notable app in App Store which able to achieve such feature**

I notice Google Keep in App Store, able to achieve such feature. By just tapping on the left most icon in their Todo list, we can immediately reorder the Todo list item.

[image]

Wondering how they did that?

---

### Approach 1: Install long press gesture on Cell's reorder icon

I had tried

1. Install long `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on cell's reorder icon.
2. Use `gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0` to mimic tap behavior.

   class TabInfoSettingsItemCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   ```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()

       ...

       let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(longPressGesture))
       gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
       reorderImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
   }
   ```

But the outcome isn't encouraging. The "move" action isn't working at all!

[image]

Complete code can be found here : https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/tree/gesture-on-cell/TabDemo

---

### Approach 2: Install long press gesture on Collection View

I had tried

1. Install long `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on Collection View
2. Use `gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0` to mimic tap behavior.

Here's the code snippet

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(longPressGesture))
 // Mimic short tap. But this blocks the events for delete button and text field :-(
 gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
 collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

But the outcome isn't perfect.

[image]

1. How can we recognise the tap event only within the reorder icon (icon with 3 horizontal lines) boundary.
2. Delete button no longer work as `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` blocks it from receiving event.
3. Text field no longer work as `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` blocks it from receiving event.

Complete code can be found here : https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/tree/gesture-on-collection-view/TabDemo

Comment: There is no such thing as "drag mode". There is no "mode" for the button to "activate". Either the user is in fact dragging or not. There is a gesture recognizer; the user must make the gesture.

Comment: @matt I have updated the question with better screenshot. In Android, when tapping the 3 horizontal lines icon, what we did is in the button click event callback, we perform `ItemTouchHelper.startDrag` call. I am not sure how to do this manually in iOS. As, iOS seem to automatically perform "startDrag" when performing long press on cell item.

Comment: We _don't_ do it manually in iOS. iOS is not Android.

Comment: OK your image with the three horizontal lines involves a completely different interface. A table view has that; it has an edit mode, and you can make the reorder lines appear. But a collection view has no edit mode and it has no three lines. You just have to accept that that is how collection views work on iOS. Maybe you wanted a table view?

Comment: Thanks @matt. We are aware of the common pattern edit/done provided by table view (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iCZVUCTrHk) We want to see whether it is still possible to implement this common pattern in collection view (We choose collection view as it gives us flexibility in cell layout). Seem not that straightforward to achieve so?

Comment: It's fine to use a collection view. But it has no built-in edit mode. If you want little handles to appear like in your drawing, that is up to you. You asked how to make a mode happen and I'm telling you there is no such mode, you have to invent it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove *UILongPressGestureRecognizer* from *UICollectionView*, Remove gesture comment from *TabInfoSettingsItemCell* class.
Replace this method in *TabInfoSettingsController*:

```
func changed(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("==changed==")
    collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: collectionView))
}
```

and try that works.

[image]

Comment: Hi, but I do not understand, if you remove `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` from `UICollectionView`, which part of the code is handling and drag-n-reorder action?

Comment: @Cheok Yan Cheng, Remove comment from *TabInfoSettingsItemCell* file. longgesture tapevent work with reorder icon.

Comment: Are u referring to this? https://github.com/yccheok/ios-tutorial/blob/gesture-on-collection-view/TabDemo/TabDemo/tab/TabInfoSettingsItemCell.swift#L33 The code has already been commented. There is nothing to remove.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng please check your code in github, i made changes in your code.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng check this https://github.com/DhawalBera/ios-tutorial/blob/patch-1/TabDemo/TabDemo/tab/TabInfoSettingsItemCell.swift

https://github.com/DhawalBera/ios-tutorial/blob/patch-1/TabDemo/TabDemo/tab/TabInfoSettingsController.swift

Comment: These are the exact same code as described in "Approach 1: Install long press gesture on Cell's reorder icon". If you run them in XCode 12, you will face the same issue as described in Approach 1.

Comment: These code same as "Approach 1" but change in this method func changed(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("==changed==")
    collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: **collectionView**))
}

Comment: Oh. Thanks. That makes sense. I try out and it works. Thank you for your efforts.